# Proving the every subspace of $V$ is a closed subset of $V$ with respect to metric $d$.

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, soft-question

> I am require to show that every finite-dimensional subspace of the
>   inner product space $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ is a closed subset
>   of $V$, with respect to the metric $d$ where $d(u,v) = ||u-v||$.

My main problem is that the definition of a closed subset is not give. So to cut things short **How do we define a closed subset of** $V$, for some context I found this in my Linear Algebra text book in the Chapter that introduces Inner Product Spaces.

Comment: What notions of "closed set" do you know of? Surely you've come across them before, possibly in other contexts.

Comment: @Arthur To be honest i only know of subspaces being closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what you already know. Is this the first time ever that you've heard of "closed sets", or have you come across the term before?

Comment: @Arthur Yes this is my first time coming across this term

Comment: @Arthur So should i skip this for now and come back when i have studied some topology?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest you skip it for now, until you've studied metric spaces.  (You may learn about them in an analysis course before you take topology.)

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your help.